# Representation theory problem 6.2 Isaacs.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $ N  \unlhd  G $ and suppose  $G/N $ is abelian. Let $C$ be the group of linear characters of $G/N $ so that $C$ acts on $Irr(G)$ by multiplication. Let $\vartheta \in Irr(N)$. Show that

$\vartheta^G=f \sum \chi_i $ where $f$ is an integer and $\chi_i \in Irr(G)$ contistute an orbit under $C$.

Try: I tried using Gallagher's theorem but couldn't use it somehow that would give me that $\beta\chi$ is a constituent, where $\chi \in Irr(G) $ such that $\chi_N =\vartheta$ and $\beta \in Ιrr(G/N) $. But First I don't know if such $\chi$ exists. Second I also know that those $\beta\chi$ for $\beta$ running in $G/N$ would give me indeed irreducible characters so they would be ok for the $\chi_i$'s the problem asks for.  Thats what I have thought so far.

COROLLARY (Gallagher) Let $N \unlhd G$  and let $\chi \in Irr(G)$ be such that
$\chi_N = θ \in Irr(N)$ . Then the characters $\beta\chi$ for $\beta  \in  Irr(G/N)$ are irreducible,
distinct for distinct $\beta$ and are all of the irreducible constituents of $\vartheta^G$.

Comment: This is Exercise (6.2) from Isaacs' book on Character Theory. You should perhaps have mentioned that, and also the fact that there is a hint in the book.

Comment: yes it is indeed.

Comment: So why are you not trying to use the hint? If you cannot do it using the hint, then it is very unlikely that you will succeed in doing it any other way. Anyway Furbini's solution uses the hint.

Comment: I wrote down my try on the problem. The hint didnt help me since these exercises are on chapter 6 i was tyring to use theorems from chapter 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a class function on $N$ and $\psi$ is a class function on $G$, there is the following well-known formula $(\phi \psi_N)^G=\phi^G\psi$.
Then if $\chi$ is an irreducible character of $G$ over $\theta$, one has that $(\chi_N 1_{N})^G=\rho_{G/N} \chi$. Since $\theta$ is a constituent of $\chi_N$, $\theta^G$ is a constituent of $\rho_{G/N}\chi$. From this follows that the irreducible constituents of $\theta$ are of the form $\lambda \chi$, with $\lambda\in \hat{G/N}$. Then they have the same multiplicity in $\theta^G$ by Frobenius reciprocity (their restriction is always $\chi_N$). It is also clear from above that they are an orbit for the multiplicative action of $\hat{G/N}$.

Comment: Hmm, it is not so clear that the $\lambda\chi$ have the same multiplicity and that they constitute an orbit.

Comment: They have the same multiplicity because $[\theta^G,\lambda\chi]=[\theta,(\lambda\chi)_N]=[\theta, (\chi)_N]$ for all $\lambda$. They are an orbit for the same reason (the above shows that every $\lambda\chi$ is a constituent).

Answer (score 2):

Let $N \unlhd G$ with $G/N$ abelian. Then we can identify $Irr(G/N)=\{\lambda \in Irr(G): N \subseteq ker(\lambda) \}$. Note that $\lambda(1)=1$, if $\lambda \in Irr(G/N)$. In addition (see for example Problem (5.3) in M.I. Isaacs, *Character Theory of Finite Groups*), if $\chi \in Irr(G)$, then $(\chi_N)^G=(\chi_N \cdot 1_N)^G=\chi \cdot (1_N)^G$. And, in general, for a *linear* $\lambda \in Irr(G)$, the product character $\lambda\chi \in Irr(G)$. 
Now, $(1_N)^G=\sum\limits_{\lambda \in Irr(G/N)}\lambda$, the regular character of $G/N$. Hence
$$(\chi_N)^G=\sum\limits_{\lambda \in Irr(G/N)} \lambda\chi \tag{1}$$

Let $\vartheta \in Irr(N)$ and let $\chi \in Irr(G)$ lying above $\vartheta$, say (applying Clifford) $$\chi_N=e\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t} \vartheta_i,\tag{2}$$ where the $\vartheta_i$'s are the distinct $G$-conjugates of $\vartheta$ and $t=|G:I_G(\vartheta)|$, the index of its inertia subgroup. Since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we have $\vartheta^G=\vartheta_i^G$ for each $i$, hence from $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows
$$et\vartheta^G=\sum\limits_{\lambda \in Irr(G/N)} \lambda\chi \tag{3}$$
Now let us calculate the multiplicity of each of $\lambda\chi$'s appearing as an irreducible constituent in the right hand-side of $(3)$ using Frobenius Reciprocity. Since $N \subseteq ker(\lambda)$, we have $\lambda_N=1_N$, hence
$$[(\chi_N)^G,\lambda\chi]=[\chi_N,(\lambda\chi)_N]=[\chi_N,(\lambda_N)(\chi_N)]=[\chi_N,\chi_N]=e^2t$$
where the last equality follows from $(2)$. So we can rewrite $(3)$ as
$$et\vartheta^G=e^2t\sum\chi_i \tag{4}$$
where the $\chi_i$ now constitute an orbit under the action of $Irr(G/N)$ on $\chi$. From $(4)$ it follows that
$$\vartheta^G=e\sum\chi_i \tag{5}$$
If $s$ is the size of the orbit above, then evaluating the character degrees at both sides in $(2)$ and $(5)$ yields $\vartheta(1)|G:N|=es\chi(1)=es\cdot et\vartheta(1)=e^2st\vartheta(1)$, so we find $|I_G(\vartheta):N|=e^2s$. With the notation above, we get the following consequence (see also, R.L. Roth, *A dual view of the Clifford Theory of Characters of Finite Groups*, Can. J. Math., Vol. XXIII, No. 5, 1971, pp. 857-865, Theorem(2.1))

**Corollary** (R.L. Roth, 1971) Let $N \unlhd G$ with $G/N$ abelian and $\chi \in Irr(G)$. Then the action of $Irr(G/N)$ fixes $\chi$ if and only if $\vartheta^G=e\chi$.
**Proof** If every $\lambda \in Irr(G/N)$ fixes $\chi$, then from $(5)$ we get $\vartheta^G=e\chi$. Conversely, since $N$ is normal, $\vartheta^G$ vanishes outside $N$, whence $\lambda\chi=\chi$ outside $N$. And of course the restriction $(\lambda\chi)_N=\chi_N$, since $N \subseteq ker(\lambda)$. So $\lambda\chi$ and $\chi$ agree on the whole $G$. $\square$